# I am getting 'list' object is not callable error for this code. I need to add zero before each element

Tags: python, recursion, combinations, memoization

```
a = [1,2,3,4]

newarray = list(map(a,[0,*a]))

print(newarray)
```

output:

> 'list' object is not callable error

expected: Add zero to each element in array

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Please **don't** tag irrelevant tags. This has nothing to do with [tag:javascript], as that clearly isn't JavaScript code (the `*a` would be a syntax error).

Comment: By 'add 0', do you mean sum the number and 0? Or rather, do you mean prepending the string 0 to the string representations of the numbers in your list?

Comment: Hi! You tried to execute some python code and got an error in a call to function `map`. The first thing to do is to check the documentation of function `map`, and make sure you called it correctly, with the appropriate parameters, and with the parameters in the correct order. The documentation is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map ; as it turns out, `map` expects a function first, and a list second, not a list first and a function second. That's what the error message is telling you: "`list object not callable`" meaning it tried to use a list as if it was a function.

Comment: prepending the string 0.. Likely output - [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4]]......... I want to achieve this using map function.. How do I use map to implement a function without referring to a function separately outside the map?

Comment: `[[0,i] for i in a]`

Comment: @SarfrazNawaz Using keyword `lambda`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a list comprehension:

```
out = [[0,x] for x in a]
```

output: `[[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4]]`

Alternatively, [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) and `zip`:

```
from itertools import repeat
out = list(zip(repeat(0), a))
# or keep a generator
# g = zip(repeat(0), a)
```

output: `[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)]`

##### strings

as your comment is not fully clear ("*prepending the string 0*"), in case you really want **strings**, you can use:

```
out = [f'0{x}' for x in a]
```

or

```
out = list(map('{:02d}'.format, a))
```

output: `['01', '02', '03', '04']`

Answer (score 0):

Builtin function `map` expects two arguments: a function and a list.

You wrote your arguments in the wrong order: you passed list `a` first instead of second.

And the thing you tried to pass as a function is not really a function.

Here is a possible fix by defining a function with `def`:

```py
def the_function_for_map(x):
    return [0, x]

newarray = list(map(the_function_for_map, a))
```

Here is a possible fix by defining a function with `lambda`:

```py
newarray = list(map(lambda x: [0, x], a))
```

And finally, here is a possible fix using a list comprehension instead of `map`:

```py
newarray = [[0, x] for x in a]
```

In your particular case, you can also use `zip` with a list full of zeroes:

```py
newarray = list(zip([0]*len(a), a))
```

Or `zip_longest` with an empty list and a default value:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

newarray = list(zip_longest([], a, fillvalue=0))
```